# IE8 Print Style CSS causing background issue

Tags: css, printing, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to make an IE8 compatible print CSS, however the browser is creating a large white div in place of what should be content.

In the regular CSS I have the following on the problem div:

```
.content-gradient {
background: @contentbg;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(45,45,45,0.8) 0%, rgba(45,45,45,1) 25%, rgba(45,45,45,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(45,45,45,0.8)), color-stop(25%,rgba(45,45,45,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(45,45,45,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(45,45,45,0.8) 0%,rgba(45,45,45,1) 25%,rgba(45,45,45,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(45,45,45,0.8) 0%,rgba(45,45,45,1) 25%,rgba(45,45,45,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(45,45,45,0.8) 0%,rgba(45,45,45,1) 25%,rgba(45,45,45,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(45,45,45,0.8) 0%,rgba(45,45,45,1) 25%,rgba(45,45,45,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cc2d2d2d', endColorstr='#2d2d2d',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

This is a LESS mixin that I am applying to the div, then in my print.css I am attempting to clear this by using: `background: #fff !important;`

When I print preview, I see a grey background with black text. When I print the file, I get a solid white div. I have zero clues as to why this is being done.

I have a bunch of global stlyes I apply to clear the usual culprits:

```
@media print {

  * {
    overflow: visible !important; // fixes Firefox print CSS overflow bug
  }

  // Reset the CSS
  body, html * {
     background: #fff !important;
     color: #000 !important;
     padding: 0 !important;
     position: static !important;
     float: none !important;
  }

  // continue with the rest of the print css
}
```

This stylesheet has already been a nightmare matching FF & Chrome. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You're saying that Print Preview looks fine, but it doesn't actually print on your printer?  Are you sure your printer has ink?  =)

Comment: Sorry, I am using XPS output, but it is coming out much different than the preview or expected output.